# Chartjs is disappearing in Ionic tabs when keyboard dismiss

Tags: javascript, android, html, ionic-framework, chart.js

I am writing an application With Ionic Framework. I used Ionic Tabs template and I wanted to add a Chart using ChartJs. I use an Android device.

The Chart is working pretty good once the view appears. But When:

- I am in Tab1.
- I try to change Tab to Tab2 that contains Input text.
- then when the keyboard is appearing, i write or not.
- I dismiss the keyboard
- I go back to the Tab1
  -The Chart is disappearing and not reappearing until closing the application.

Any Help Please?

Answer (score 0):

Not played around with Chart.js in the environment you described, but I would make sure your data specifies the color property in each data point.